# Win32 api call Error GetShortPathName in f#

Tags: winapi, f#

I can get this code to run in the interactive environment but it crashes when I run the code from debugger or from the .exe file

Forgot the error: 
FatalExecutionEngineError was detected!
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6c9781b0, on thread 0x1104. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Using .net 4.5

```
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Text

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)>]
extern uint32 GetShortPathName(
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>] string longpath, 
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>] StringBuilder shortpath, 
    [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)>] uint32  item)

let MakeShortName(longPath : string) =
    let sb =  StringBuilder()
    let currPath = longPath
    let item = 1024u

   // let blah = ""
    //win32 assigns shortPath
    let blah32 = GetShortPathName(currPath, sb, item)

    sb.ToString()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let path = @"C:\dev\shortName\shortName"
    let shorty = MakeShortName path
    printfn "%s" shorty 
    let x = System.Console.ReadKey()

    0
```

Interactive env

---

$ (me alt+entering the above two functions)

val GetShortPathName : string * StringBuilder * uint32 -> uint32
val MakeShortName : string -> string

$ MakeShortName @"C:\dev\shortName\shortName";;
val it : string = "C:\dev\SHORTN~1\SHORTN~1"

Comment: If you solved your own question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: It won't let me for 8 hours not enough rep =/

Comment: @DaveHanson we have lowered the rep requirements for self answering - please try answering again

Comment: Get rid of every `MarshalAs` attribute -- 100% of them are pointless here.

Comment: Cool thanks Geoff I can't accept my own answer for two days, but I was able to post it this time.

Comment: I rolled back the question since the solution is now in an answer. :)

Comment: Your right ildjarn tested the answer without the marshals and it works fine without them too. I updated the answer because it is more correct IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it.

I just suck @ win 32

Removed marshals

See solution:

```
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Text

[<DllImport("kernel32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)>]
extern int GetShortPathName(
    string longpath, 
    StringBuilder shortpath, 
    int  item)

let MakeShortName(longPath : string) =
    let sb =  StringBuilder()
    let currPath = longPath
    let item = 1024

   // let blah = ""
//win32 assigns shortPath
    let blah32 = GetShortPathName(currPath, sb, item)

    sb.ToString()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

let path = @"C:\dev\shortName\shortName"
let shorty = MakeShortName path
printfn "%s" shorty 
let x = System.Console.ReadKey()

0
```

Answer (score 0):

Win32 functions may expect a pre-allocated buffer of the maximum size. This code fixed the crash, for me:

```
let MakeShortName(longPath : string) =
    let maxSize = uint32 <| longPath.Length + 16
    let sb =  new StringBuilder("", int32 maxSize)
    let len = GetShortPathName(longPath, sb, maxSize)
    sb.ToString(0, int32 len)
```